# LDAP filter : getting only users updated since given date

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have trouble setting up an Active Directory filter to synchronize a MySQL database containing all my users. And I can not create a filter that only retrieves users with an update date greater than a given date.

I tried using uSNChanged attribute on my filter but it returns me 0 result.

Any suggestion is welcome thanks to all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would search by the `whenChanged` attribute. Something like this:

```
(&(whenChanged>=20180425150000.0-0400)(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))
```

The format is pretty straight forward:

```
{year}{month}{date}{hour}{minute}{seconds}.{milliseconds}-{timezone}
```

For example, in my example above I used today's date at 3:00pm eastern.

There are a couple caveats to keep in mind:

1. The `whenChanged` attribute is not exactly the same on every domain controller, but they will be close (within a half hour). The reason is because of replication - the time is set to the time each DC received the change.
2. When a user logs in, the `lastLogon` time is updated, and that triggers the `whenChanged` attribute to be updated. So just because `whenChanged` changes, it doesn't mean someone modified the account. This also means that this search will return more accounts than you may expect.

Comment: {year}{month}{date}{hour}{minute}{seconds}.{milliseconds}-{timezone}
Data time format is very impotent while applying filter to ldap